# Regarding Internet Connection Tethering Bar Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Please suggest me the way to get the height of tethering bar, showing the internet connection info. Actually when I am getting the height of status bar its returing 20, even the is tethering bar showing on the screen. So please let me know how to get the actual height of status bar and tethering bar.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGRect rect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]` to get the status bar frame.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarFrame